# Extra fields for Magento Custom Options

Tags: magento

Hi I want to know whether its possible to add new fields in the admin panel while adding custom options for a product.

For example:

by default when you add custom options there's options such as Title *, Input Type *,Is Required ans Sort Order.

I want to add one more field there called description or something which will be like a short description about that option.

Thanks

Comment: Having done this once I can say it is not easy, it's one of the rare places that Magento doesn't like being extended. If you're new to Magento or programming then I say this is an occasion where hiring a professional is less costly than having your store non-operational for the weeks it takes to learn enough. I'm deliberately posting this as a comment because I don't want to say it's impossible, I hope someone has a real answer for you.

Comment: There has to be some way out!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Adding a extra field in product’s custom options :
Add html for the extra field:

Open file
app\design\adminhtml\default\default\template\catalog\product\edit\options\option.phtml
Add this line for text field

```
 '<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="<?php echo $this->getFieldName() ?>[{{id}}][css_class]" value="{{css_class}}"></td>'+
```

right after this line
'getRequireSelectHtml() ?>'+

2) add '__('filed name') ?>'+
after

```
'<th class="opt-req"><?php echo $this->jsQuoteEscape(Mage::helper('catalog')->__('Is Required')) ?></th>'+
```

This will add a html input text right after required drop-down.

Add functionality to save the data from our newly created field in back-end,

open file
app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Catalog\Product\Edit\Tab\Options\Option.php

3) 
in method getOptionValues()
add

```
  $value['css_class'] = $option->getCssClass();
```

and add

```
'css_class' => $option->getCssClass()
```

this after

```
'sort_order' => $_value->getSortOrder(),
```

Now add a database column ‘new_Coumn’ in database
table ‘catalog_product_option’

To get this field on frontend $_option->getCssClass(); cssClass is fieldname you have to use your.